# How to display data from Response after post method on flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, post

I have completed my post method and after that, data from api will be seen in terminal in json format, now I have also made response model for that but now how do i fetch those data and display in text?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is using [`Json Serialization`](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/automatic-generate-json-serializable-in-flutter-4c9d2d23ed88).

But here I'll use a shorter route.

Let me show you an example using [`json placeholder mock api`](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/):

Returned json is just like this:

```
{
 "id": 101
}
```

Create a model class using auto generation tool : [`quicktype.io`](https://app.quicktype.io/)
The generated `ResponseModel` class is as follows:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final responseModel = responseModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ResponseModel responseModelFromJson(String str) => ResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String responseModelToJson(ResponseModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ResponseModel {
    ResponseModel({
        this.id,
    });

    int id;

    ResponseModel copyWith({
        int id,
    }) => 
        ResponseModel(
            id: id ?? this.id,
        );

    factory ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseModel(
        id: json["id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
    };
}
```

And then create a api call:

```
ResponseModel apiCall() async{
late ResponseModel model;
Map<String, String> body = {};

final response = await 
http.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", body: body);

//// 201 status is post created status
/// 200 status is ok status
if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  ///Convert json to ResponseModel class
  model = ResponseModel.fromJson(response.body);
  return model;
}
 throw Error();
}
```

And in your UI, you can call in your `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
FutureBuilder( 
future: apiCall(), // async api call work
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
   switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
     case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading....');
     default:
       if (snapshot.hasError){
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
       }
       else{
      ///Here fetch api response
      ResponseModel response = snapshot.data;
      
      /// print id on terminal
      debugPrint("ID ${response.id}");

      /// Use it in text
      return Text('Result: ${response.id}');
      }
    }
  },
 );
```

**Happy Coding TT**